# Taking picture with Android app rotation fail - always in landscape layout

Tags: android, image, image-processing

When I take a picture on the phone, with Android app the image is not properly rotated, it is always in landscape no matter what I do.

here is the code how I call camera app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPictureFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PHOTO);
```

here is the on ActivitiResult method:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
        return;
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO){
        //here I show picture, but beside shove it, I need also rotate it.
        //data are here null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read exif of picture file and rotate it correct programmatically:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());

int rotation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
switch(rotation){
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:{
    }break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:{
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 
                matrix, true);
    }break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:{
        matrix.postRotate(180);
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
    }break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:{
        matrix.postRotate(270);
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 
                matrix, true);
    }break;
}

// convert bitmap to jpeg with 50% compression
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(pictureFile));
```